# Install MSVC offline

Tags: virtualbox, installation

I downloaded MSVC 20117 to run an offline installer inside VirtualBox, and then run:

```
vs_Community.exe --noweb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --includeOptional
```

However I still receive an error:

You may not be connected to the network

Looking at the log produced I see following:

```
2020-12-03T12:46:00 : Verbose : Visual Studio Installer (1.18.1113.826 : release) ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vs_installershell.exe","/finalizeInstall","install","--layoutPath","C:\\Users\\igor\\msvc2017","--in","C:\\Users\\igor\\msvc2017\\Response.json","--noweb","--add","Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop","--includeRecommended","--includeOptional","--locale","en-US","--activityId","9048e0f3-53df-40d0-bf0c-3df790fb0baf","--pipe","4686f077-e5af-4e8a-a4f3-38ad5d0af050"]
2020-12-03T12:46:17 : Verbose : Received the application ready notification
2020-12-03T12:46:19 : Verbose : ProgressBarService listening to ipc channel: progress-bar
2020-12-03T12:46:19 : Verbose : LoggerIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: LoggerService
2020-12-03T12:46:19 : Verbose : LoggerIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: LoggerService
2020-12-03T12:46:19 : Verbose : Telemetry Session ID: b73cb039-2177-46ac-a792-49c61b1cd05c
2020-12-03T12:46:19 : Verbose : Starting ServiceHub Remote Settings client.
2020-12-03T12:46:20 : Verbose : Creating VS Telemetry Survey
2020-12-03T12:46:20 : Verbose : Creating commonError Service
2020-12-03T12:46:21 : Verbose : starting rpc process for common error
2020-12-03T12:46:21 : Verbose : RPC Factory: Get common error config provider
2020-12-03T12:46:21 : Verbose : FeaturesIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: FeaturesProxy
2020-12-03T12:46:21 : Verbose : FeaturesIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: FeaturesProxy
2020-12-03T12:46:21 : Verbose : Starting the installer service.
2020-12-03T12:46:25 : Verbose : Installation finalized successfully.
2020-12-03T12:46:32 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '0'
2020-12-03T12:46:32 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '0'
2020-12-03T12:46:34 : Verbose : Window showing
2020-12-03T12:46:34 : Verbose : No pipe connection
2020-12-03T12:46:37 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '1'
2020-12-03T12:46:37 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '1'
2020-12-03T12:46:42 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '2'
2020-12-03T12:46:42 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '2'
2020-12-03T12:46:47 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '3'
2020-12-03T12:46:48 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '3'
2020-12-03T12:46:52 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '4'
2020-12-03T12:46:53 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '4'
2020-12-03T12:46:58 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '5'
2020-12-03T12:46:58 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '5'
2020-12-03T12:47:03 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '6'
2020-12-03T12:47:03 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '6'
2020-12-03T12:47:08 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '7'
2020-12-03T12:47:08 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '7'
2020-12-03T12:47:13 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '8'
2020-12-03T12:47:14 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '8'
2020-12-03T12:47:19 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '9'
2020-12-03T12:47:19 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '9'
2020-12-03T12:47:24 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '10'
2020-12-03T12:47:24 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '10'
2020-12-03T12:47:29 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '11'
2020-12-03T12:47:29 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'Installer' - attempt '11'
2020-12-03T12:47:34 : Error : Retrying attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient' - attempt '12'
```

and then it eventually dies.

And I don't understand this - I did give --noweb option. So what is wrong?

Comment: You might want to correct the numerous typos in your question

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm sorry but even with my ESL eyes, I can't see any. Also, for some unnown reason, when I switched the host (I attached the VM to Windows, instead of Linux) the install process started.

Comment: Somebody did it for you.

Comment: @ramhound, do you know why it didn't work with Linux host and started with windows?

Comment: What does Linux have to do with Visual Studio running on Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm sorry, I just marked the question with `VirtualBox`, but didn't explicitly mentioned it. Fixed it now.

Comment: Still don’t understand the Linux connection

Comment: @Ramhound, when the Linux was host - installation failed.